# Diffrence between bash script.sh and ./script.sh

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose we have **`env.sh`** file that contains:

> `echo $(history | tail -n2 | head -n1) | sed 's/[0-9]* //'` #looking for the last typed command

when executing this script with **`bash env.sh`**, the output will be empty:

[image]

but when we execute the script with `./env.sh`, we get the last typed command:

[image]

I just want to know the diffrence between them

Notice that if we add **`#!/bin/bash`** at the beginning of the script, the `./env.sh` will no longer output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History is disabled by BASH in non-interactive shells by-default. If you want to enable it however, you can do so like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $HISTFILE # will be empty in non-iteractive shell

HISTFILE=~/.bash_history # set it again
set -o history
# the command will work now
history
```

The reason this is done is to avoid cluttering the history by any commands being run by any shell scripts.

Adding hashbang (meaning the file is to be interpreted as a script by the program specified in your hashbang) to your script when being run via `./env.sh` invokes your script using the binary `/bin/bash` i.e. run via `bash`, thus again printing no history.